# Send MySQL data to Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am confused on how we can send MySQL data from MySQL database deployed in an EC2 instance to an Amazon RedShift cluster.

What are the ways that can be used for doing this task?

Comment: How often do you wish to do this? Is it a daily task, or continuous throughout the day? How much data? Feel free to Edit your question to add more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solutions:

1. Easiest solution should be "AWS Data Pipeline".
2. write output of your SQL Query into a CSV file --> zip it ( if huge data ) --> upload to S3 --> Use Redshift copy command to upload all these records in bulk into redshift.